# Getting error "passed value is 0.000000" when passing float less than 1 on some trading pairs

Tags: pine-script

I have the following code in pine script:

`strategy.entry("REV", strategy.long, comment="REV", qty=0.9)`

Running it against the ticker `SHITPERP` on the FTX exchange gives the error:

“quantity for entry or order must be a positive number less or equal to 1000000000.000000, passed value is 0.000000 “

The `qty` value appears to be rounded to zero. If I change it to say 1.9 then it works but the resulting position size is 1

These orders work just fine in the exchange itself and are not rounded down to the nearest integer.

Is there some sort of minimum order size limit when using strategy.entry  or strategy.order? Is there a variable I can check or calculation necessary to make orders like this not throw errors? I run into this problem with various scripts on different assets

I also checked `syminfo.mintick` and `syminfo.pointvalue` to see if there is some clue there and they are 0.1 and 1 respectively

The only thing I can think of is maybe some sort of currency conversion  but I am not setting the currency on the strategy and the base pair for the asset is USD stable coin. Even if I set the currency to USD the same problem occurs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from @Pinecoders in the trading view chat. Seems that there is a step value for assets and for some like the `SHITPERP` it isn't defined yet. In that case it defaults to 1 which means that partial orders will be rounded down to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer!
This error bugged me since they upgrade to Pine 4.0
Now I know where to fix it :)

Simple solution; put some if to check if variable is less than 1, then assign 1 to it.

```
unit_size = ( result of position size calculation )

if (unit_size < 1)
    unit_size := 1

strategy.entry("REV", strategy.long, comment="REV", qty=unit_size)
```

Or you can change unit_size to -1 so and use "if" to check before strategy.entry command

```
if (unit_size < 1)
    unit_size := -1
if (unit_size > 0 )
    strategy.entry("REV", strategy.long, comment="REV", qty=unit_size)
```

To avoid position size is more than your initial capital.